# Slim - How to close ruby tag in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, slim-lang

I want to close a `f.radio-button` tag so that I can add some text after a radio button.

I have tried the following below, but the `/` is giving me an error so I don't think this is the proper way to do it.

```
= f.radio_button :budget_type, 'budget', :checked => true/ Budget Account
```

How do I close my `f.radio_button` tag so that it looks something similar to this:

```
= <%= f.radio_button :budget_type, 'budget', :checked => true %>Budget Account
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `|` at the beginning of line to indicate text.

```
= f.radio_button :budget_type, 'budget', :checked => true
| Budget Account
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you mind explaining what the pipe does? I've read the documentation, but it doesn't make sense to me:

`The pipe tells Slim to just copy the line. It essentially escapes any processing. Each following line that is indented greater than the pipe is copied over.`

Comment: I just understood it as plain text and used it like such :) Despite that explanation, Slim doc actually has examples to use it to show plain text, if I remembered correctly.